# ActionBar animation does not stop

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBar Sherlock with a number of fragments.

The app I am building is a basic RSS reader much like the one shown here (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_qR2glTTAs), except that there are multiple tabs for several different RSS feeds. When a tab is clicked, I replace the active fragment with the appropriate new fragment.

I am trying to get ActionBar animated refresh button functionality much like it is depicted in the YouTube video above. Basically, when the user clicks the refresh button, I expect the refresh button to rotate until the refresh is complete. If the user switches tabs while the current tab is refreshing, I want to show a refresh button that is NOT rotating.

The problem is: after I click on the refresh button and the button starts rotating, if I switch to another tab, I simply get a non-rotating refresh button on top of the rotating refresh button! This happens despite my calling `menu.clear()` and recreating the menu each time a tab is clicked. Interestingly, rotating the device causes the extra rotating refresh buttons to disappear.

Nothing I've tried seems to be able to stop the refresh animation when I change tabs! Any ideas why? I can post more of my code here if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that you are animating and / or creating the menu inside your fragements... if this is the case do the things you want to do with your menu in the FragmentActivity
By the way, the effect you experience while rotating the screen is caused by the android architecture. Android always recreates the view if you are switching from portrait to landscape mode or the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried this both ways: where the menu is created in each fragment, and where the menu creation and changes occur in the parent FragmentActivity. So far, neither seems to allow me to stop the animation before the tab changes.